# October CMS Modify the files in "modules" directory?

Tags: octobercms

I just installed October CMS, and I have so many questions. But one of them is, I want to modify some things in backend, and so I think the files are in modules/cms and modules/backend. So, my question is, can I modify this files directly? Or is there a better practice for these case? Perhaps a way overwriting functionality without touch the original files?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is a bad practice to modify core files! Try to use [events](http://octobercms.com/docs/services/events) or create patches.